# How to target all elements besides the first with nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I target all paragraphs inside a given DIV beside the first one using the `:nth-child` operator?

```css
:nth-child(/* select all but the first one */) {
     color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Example 1</p>
    <p>Example 2</p>
    <p>Example 3</p>
    <p>Example 4</p>
    <p>Example 5</p>
    <p>Example 6</p>
    <p>Example 7</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
:nth-child(n+1)
```

or for some browsers:

```
:nth-child(n+2)
```

W3Schools says:

> Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.
>
> [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Or you can use separate `:first-child` CSS declaration for this first element.

Comment: Please, change it to n+2, because otherwise it targets all elements, including the first.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
p:nth-child(n+2) {
    color: green;   
}
```

[**working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R9rxu/1)

[`Reference`](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
div > p:nth-child(n+2)
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Q6FDq/